# scrlayer-scrpage not setting headmark properly for non-sections

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

This is my document setup:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline=true]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\small}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}


\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\star$}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage[printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}

\usepackage[
german,
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue, 
anchorcolor=black,
citecolor=green, 
urlcolor=cyan 
]{hyperref}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
```

In addition to the table of contents, I have three other sections which I do not want to be numbered:
First one is the list of acronyms:

```
\section*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\pdfbookmark[2]{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}{toc}

\begin{acronym}[header=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]
    \acro{kiss}[KISS]{Keep it simple stupid}
    \acro{st}[ST]{Some Test}
\end{acronym}

\clearpage
```

Second is the list of illustrations:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
```

and third is the bibliography at the end of the document:

```
\section*{Literaturverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

using section* and addcontentsline, I was able to put these into my table of contents without numbers, which is fine. The pagetitle, however, doesn't work properly: only the headmark for the second case, the list of illustrations, is correct. The other two keep the pagetitle from the section before.

I scoured the web for similar problems and tried to find the logic that creates the headmarks in the manual too, but the inconsistency between the second case working (without any section even!) and the first and third not working has me very confused. Is the \listoffigures-command already considered in KKOMA-Script, so that it works while the others do not? Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use all this manual \pdfbookmark and \addcontentsline. All normal things work in KOMA either by default or through some options. Here an example, the newpages are only to force new pages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, 
  headsepline=true,
  listof=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\small}


\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{some text}
\cite{doody}

\newpage
\addsec{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

\newpage

\listoffigures

\newpage
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching some more I found a solution here: http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?72513-Package-Acronym-Abk%FCrzungsverzeichnis-nach-Inhaltsverzeichnis (in german)

using \addsec over \section* and \addcontentsline works for what I want to do. Header is now appropriate!

Comment: Don't use five year old solutions. KOMA has changed and improved a lot in the last years.